# IText - How to add a JEDMICS C4 image to a pdf

Tags: c#, java, pdf, itext

I want to compile a pdf file from different image types on the fly.  I don't have any issue adding image types of jpg,gif and some other common image types,.

Issue:
I have C4 image type, that is where I am having issue adding to the pdf. [JEDMICS C4 Image Document](https://www.jedmics.net/public/C4-Img-Spec.pdf).

I am lost where to start on this, any idea, reference or code sample that can gets me in the right direction is appreciated.

Java/C# code sample is okay. Thanks.

Comment: I've never heard about JEDMICS C4 images. They aren't supported in iText.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie What would be a possible way to add images which aren't supported in iText, is it possible to extend iText for that? I have your book if you can point me to any page I can read or any other reference.

Comment: Second edition: p330-332. This doesn't explain the nitty-gritty details, but shows that all image functionality is somehow related to the `Image` class.

Comment: If you don't mind executing an external native code module, I can probably help you. Email me directly (bitbank@pobox.com).